# How to make the scrollview do not overflow in tablerow

Tags: android, user-interface

I want to make a layout that it

LinearLayout

ScrollView

LinearLayout

but it seems like the ScrollView has cover the rest of LinearLayout.

```
 LinearLayout all = new LinearLayout(this);

   LinearLayout upper = new LinearLayout(this);


   LinearLayout footer = new LinearLayout(this);

   ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);

   all.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
   upper.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
   footer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

   TextView code = new TextView(this);

   code.setText("Code : ");

   EditText codeEdit = new EditText(this);

   upper.addView(code);
   upper.addView(codeEdit);

   LinkedList<LinearLayout> lk = new LinkedList<LinearLayout>();
   TextView[] tt = new TextView[100];

   LinearLayout ll= new LinearLayout(this);
   ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

  for(int a = 0 ; a < 100; a++){
      LinearLayout temp = new LinearLayout(this);

       temp.setOrientation(temp.HORIZONTAL);

       tt[a] = new TextView(this);

       tt[a].setText("Hello " + a);

       temp.addView(tt[a]);

       lk.add(temp);

       ll.addView(temp);
   }

   sv.addView(ll);

   Button next = new Button(this);

   next.setText("Next");

   footer.addView(next);


   all.addView(upper);
  all.addView(sv);
  all.addView(footer);

    setContentView(all);
```

The scrollview is too large and cover the rest of the linearlayout, the linearlayout after is not showing becasue of the scrollview. 
How can I actually solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this

```
LinearLayout dummy = new LinearLayout(this);
        dummy.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));

        dummy.addView(sv);
```

add one linearlayout to wrap the scrollview inside it

instead of adding scroolview add this dummy linearlayout

Comment: Thank you. could you explain what is the 1 stand for?

Comment: it  is weight for linear layout